# Помогите разобраться в документации

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Читаю документацию sqlalchemy для orm, конкретно для связей.
И возник ряд вопросов:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = mapped_column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    username = mapped_column(String)
    first_name = mapped_column(String)
    last_name = mapped_column(String)
    password = mapped_column(String)
    email = mapped_column(String, unique=True)
    is_active = mapped_column(Boolean, default=False)
    is_admin = mapped_column(Boolean, default=True)
    products = relationship('Product', back_populates='user', uselist=True)


class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'product'
    id = mapped_column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    name = mapped_column(String)
    owner_id = mapped_column(ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=True)
```

При указании ower_id в Product у меня формируется внешний ключ(user.id) на таблицу user ?

И большинство вопросов именно по relationship:
relationship нужно указывать только в одной таблице?

Правильно ли я понимаю, что relationship даст мне обращаться через user к продуктам через user.products?

Правильно ли я понимаю, что аргумент back_populates делает обратное связывание и даст мне обращаться через Product к User следующим образом: product.user.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что без этого аргумента я мог бы обращаться к User, в случае если бы прописал user = relationship('User') в Product.

формирует ли sqlalcemy имена, если не указывать relationship, к примеру:

product._user

user._product

И на завершение:

sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Mapper 'Mapper[Product(product)]' has no property 'user'.  If this property was indicated from other mappers or configure events, ensure registr
y.configure() has been called.

Ошибка возникает потому что мне нужно переименовать поле owner_id в user?

Тогда какой смысл в back_populates, я думал мы де-факто привязываем имя по которому сможем обращаться к product.user по внешнему ключу owner_id?